# Get gradle dependencies programmatically

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, android-gradle-7.0

I want to get the dependencies programmatically within Gradle in an Android project.

I tried (in both project as well as module level gradle.build):

```
task dumpDependencies {
    doLast {
        def resolved = configurations.compileClasspath.resolvedConfiguration
        println "Files: $resolved.files"
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'compileClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.
```

I am using Gradle version 7.5

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compileClasspath` configuration is provided by the `java` plugin, see more at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management.

So to access the `compileClasspath` configuration, plugin Java declaration is required

```
plugins {
   id 'java'
}
```

For Android projects, which by default use `kotlin` plugin instead, there are no `compileClasspath` configurations. I could think of this alternative solution:

```
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
def implementationResolved = configurations.implementation.resolvedConfiguration
println "Implementation files: $implementationResolved.files"

configurations.compileOnly.setCanBeResolved(true)
def compileResolved = configurations.compileOnly.resolvedConfiguration
println "Compile only files: $compileResolved.files"

def files = implementationResolved.files + compileResolved.files
println "Files: $files"
```

Comment: Android Studio has java built-in I suppose, I cannot add this plugin.

Comment: minh, you are right. After I changed to the valid configuration `debugRuntimeClasspath` it worked!